# Combine class template default parameters and variadic parameters

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am designing a `Host` class that uses a fixed number of `Policies` classes, around 3 or 4.

Because for each `Policy` in the design there will always be a trivial implementation, it would be nice to default the template parameter to the trivial type, in order to ease the use of the `Host` class by its clients.

```
class IdiotBenchPolicy {};
class IdiotLoggerPolicy {};
// ...

template <typename BenchmarkPolicy = IdiotBenchPolicy, 
          typename LoggerPolicy = IdiotLoggerPolicy>
class Host
{
     BenchmarkPolicy m_bench;
     IdiotLoggerPolicy m_logger;
};
```

This allow to instantiate a `Host` without having to specify a long list of template parameters.

This is fine until the `Host` class must also take a variable number of arithmetic types. When splitting the problem, and forgetting about the `Policies`, I am able to use a variadic template parameter:

```
template <class... Args>
class Host
{
    template <class ...Var_Args>
    using are_arithmetic = typename std::conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Var_Args>...>::type;

    static_assert(are_arithmetic<Args...>::value, "Args are not all arithmetic type");
    std::tuple<Args...> m_args;
};
```

Note that even though `Host` uses a tuple internally, It'd be better not to enforce it on the class clients unless necessary.

My problem now, is to combine the two behaviors. How to instantiate a `Host` class without having to specify the `Policies` if the "default" is sufficient. I am not sure how to express this with C++ template syntax, but my intuition tells me it is possible by juggling with SFINAE and std::enable_if, however I struggle to see how.

What I'd like to be able to write is:

```
Host<int, int, float> h; //Using both default policies
Host<SmarterBenchPolicy, float, double> h2; //Using SmarterBenchPolicy, IdiotLoggerPolicy and two arithmetic types
Host<SmarterBenchPolicy>; //Using SmarterBenchPolicy, IdiotLoggerPolicy and no arithmetic type
```

How such a `Host` class, that is constructible using instantiations similar to those specified above, would be implemented ?

Comment: A workaround could be to expect a `TypeListHolder<Args...>` (with `template<class...> class TypeListHolder`) instead of `Args...` and pass `type_list<int, float /*...*/>` (with `template<class...> struct type_list {};`) instead of `int, float /*...*/`

Comment: Alternatively, you could have traits classes telling you whether a class is a suitable Policy and specialize depending on whether the first template arguments are "suitable policy classes" or seemingly arbitrary types intended for the variadic parameter pack.

Comment: @Caninonos I thought about your second solution, but as far I understand it, it would mean that `Host` only takes a `Args...` as template parameter and then tries to unpack each of the Arg into one of the Policy type using policy traits. I only want to write the implementation of `Host` once however, so this mean calling the main template version from the specializations ?

Comment: Well, basically, you could do it like this: https://ideone.com/FokpOQ and leverage inheritance to avoid rewriting the implementation of Host.

Comment: @Caninonos Here the inheritance is public but I figure it is possible to inherit privately and define a `bench` method in `Host` and then call `tell_me_what_you_chose` from within ? Would it be possible to use composition with `Host_aux` ?

Comment: That certainly is possible, although I don't think that's the most problematic point (to be fair, there are a few other flaws in my example). The one concerning me the most being that `Host<int>` and `Host<BenchPolicy, int>` are technically two different classes from the compiler point of view... although they do inherit from a common base (namely `Host_aux<IdiotBenchPolicy, type_list<int>, void>`). (I also said slicing in a comment, but slicing isn't exactly the problem per se, although I hope it's clear what I meant)

Comment: Here is a revised version ( https://ideone.com/POcxk9 ) that doesn't rely on inheritance to implement `Host` (the implementation is in `Host_impl` and `Host` simply is an alias with `Host_impl` with default policy possibly filled in in its template parameters).

Comment: @Caninonos I understand your implementation might not be perfect; But still you answered some of my main concern that was how to "read" the parameter pack to extract either `policies` or arithmetic types. Now because Host_aux expect to receive either a `BenchPolicy` or not as the Head of the typelist, it is not possible to use two `policies` ?

Comment: It is, I only limited myself to a single one for simplicity's sake. Basically, instead of a single Host_aux, you'll have two. The first one checks whether the first element is a bench_policy (and adds the default one if it isn't), then delegates to Host_aux2 which in turn checks if the second element is a logger_policy (and adds the default one if it isn't)...

Comment: Here's a simpler version that handles mutiple default arguments https://ideone.com/6iXM4F (the behaviour is a bit strange: you can override previously defined arguments), now, I guess I'll stop flooding these comments.

Comment: @Caninonos By mixing your solution #2 and #3 I come quite close to what I expected, apart from the minor inconvenience that you pointed that you can override policies

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better if you put those parameters with default values at the and of the parameter list. The variadic parameters can be packed into a `std::tuple`:

```
template <class ArgsPack,
          typename BenchmarkPolicy = IdiotBenchPolicy,
          typename LoggerPolicy = IdiotLoggerPolicy,
          std::enable_if_t<detail::is_tuple<ArgsPack>::value, int> = 0
          >
struct Host
{
    BenchmarkPolicy     bench;
    LoggerPolicy        logger;
    ArgsPack            args;

    void show_all() {
        detail::tuple_foreach([](const auto &e) {std::cout << e << "\n";}, args);
    }
};

Host<std::tuple<int, int, float>, SmartBenchPolicy> h;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. It would have to be extended to two Policy parameters except one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

struct BenchPolicyBase {

};

struct BenchPolicy1 : BenchPolicyBase {

};

template <class enabler, class... Args>
class HostClass
{
    //Use default policy
    public:
    HostClass() { std::cout << "default" << std::endl; }
    template <class ...Var_Args>
    using are_arithmetic = typename std::conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Var_Args>...>::type;

    static_assert(are_arithmetic<Args...>::value, "Args are not all arithmetic type");
    std::tuple<Args...> m_args;

    BenchPolicyBase m_bench;
};

template <typename T, typename... Rest>
using Host = HostClass<void, T, Rest...>;

template <class BenchPolicy, class... Args>
class HostClass<std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<BenchPolicyBase, BenchPolicy>::value>, BenchPolicy, Args...>
{
    //Use BenchPolicy
    public:
    HostClass() { std::cout << "Bench" << std::endl; }
    template <class ...Var_Args>
    using are_arithmetic = typename std::conjunction<std::is_arithmetic<Var_Args>...>::type;

    static_assert(are_arithmetic<Args...>::value, "Args are not all arithmetic type");
    std::tuple<Args...> m_args;

    BenchPolicy m_bench;
};

int main() {
    Host<int, long> a;
    Host<BenchPolicy1, int, long> b;
    return 0;
}
```